# button_to gives me the error of unexpected '\n'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why doesn't this code work

```
= button_to 'del', {controller: 'my_controller', action: 'my_action'}, method: :delete, {style: 'float: left;'}
```

it gives me the error of `syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC`

But if I change it to be  `= button_to 'del'` then it works well.

How did I wrong and how do all the parameters I have to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `method: :delete` in curly braces.

```
button_to 'del', {controller: 'my_controller', action: 'my_action'}, {method: :delete}, {style: 'float: left;'}
```

works.